# How to convert c struct definitions to c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, tcp

```
iov[0] = (struct iovec) {
    .iov_base = &req,
    .iov_len = sizeof(req)
};
```

I'm trying to convert a bit of code from the ss network utility to c++, and the above and similar keeps giving these errors:

```
main.cpp|83|error: expected primary-    expression before ‘struct’
main.cpp|83|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘struct’
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ doesn't support that syntax. Try this:

```
iovec iov[2];
iov[0].iov_base = &req;
iov[0].iov_len = sizeof req;
/* ... */
```

Or maybe:

```
iovec iov[] = {
    {
       &req, sizeof req
    },
    /* ... */
}
```

What you were trying is a C99 feature called "compound literals". Also, the `.iov_base` thing is called a "designated initializer".

Comment: Are compound literals avaiable in c++11?

Comment: @JaredKrumsie Not sure but don't think so. However g++ should suport it as an extension.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. Quick and helpful answers like your's are what make me come back to this site when I get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Compound literals are not present in C++. You can assign the struct members individually as `cnicutar` suggested or you can also define a temporary object and then assign it to `iov` first array element. Like this:

```
iovec iov_temp = {&req, sizeof req}; 
iov[0] = iov_temp;
```